How to parse XML with two elements with the same name?
I need to parse this XML returned by Retrofit:
<data>
    <id>1</id>
    <subdata>
        <id>1a</id>
    </subdata>
    <subdata>
        <id>1b</id>
    </subdata>
</data>

I'm using Jackson:
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://www.web.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(XmlMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        .registerKotlinModule()))
    .build().create(DataApiService::class.java)

I tried with these data classes for the object:
data class Data(
    val id: String,
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "subdata")
    val subdata1: SubData,
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "subdata")
    val subdata2: SubData
)

data class SubData(
    val id: String,
)

But it doesn't work:
IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "subdata": com.data.model.Data#getSubdata1() vs com.data.model.Data#getSubdata2()


Wild guess: have you tried declaring an array of SubData instead?

yes, didn't work neither, I tryed as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68659128/479886 but didn't work, as you can see in my question the XML doesn't have an array, instead, it haves two elements with the same name

Try @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) on the List property. Since your SubData is directly underneath <data>

@Raildex didn't work, Conflicting getter definitions for property "subdata": com..data.model.SubDataWrapper#getData1() vs com..data.model.SubDataWrapper#getData2()

and without that false gives another error:
Could not find creator property with name 'subdata'

Can you show the updated class? See here how it should look like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041861/jackson-xml-to-pojo-array-without-wrapper

wow, doing like in that link worked! please post an answer and I'll accepting it :) thanks

You can use the Annotation @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) to tell Jackson that you have multiple elements with the same name and de/serialize it as a List<Subdata>:
data class Data(
    val id: String,
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "subdata")
    val subdata: List<SubData>
)

data class SubData(
    val id: String,
)

useWrapping = false tells Jackson that your XML elements are directly underneath the root and not underneath a separate Wrapper.
